# How to deploy a deployment in another namespace in Kubernetes?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins deployed on Kubernetes. Jenkins pods are deployed in 'kubernetes-plugin' namespace, and uses service account 'jenkins', which is defined below:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
```

But when I use `kubectl apply -f web-api-deploy.yaml -n default` in the jenkins pipeline, it report the following error:

```
deployments.extensions "news-app-web-api-dev" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-plugin:jenkins" cannot get deployments.extensions in the namespace "default"
```

which means: you cannot deploy on namespace 'default' when using service account 'jenkins' in namespace 'kubernetes-plugin'

So is there a way to deploy a deployment in another namespace?? How.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to deploy a deployment in another namespace?? How.

If I'm not mistaken, [this github project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) gives steps to run in different namespace. It all boils down to this:

You need to craete ServiceAccount, Role and RoleBinding in different namespace and use it like noted in documentation. Here is relevant part:

```
Ensure you create the namespaces and roles with the following commands,
then run the tests in namespace kubernetes-plugin with the service account
jenkins (edit src/test/kubernetes/service-account.yml to use a different 
service account)

kubectl create namespace kubernetes-plugin-test
kubectl create namespace kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace
kubectl create namespace kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace2
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test -f src/main/kubernetes/service-account.yml
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace -f src/main/kubernetes/service-account.yml
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace2 -f src/main/kubernetes/service-account.yml
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test -f src/test/kubernetes/service-account.yml
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace -f src/test/kubernetes/service-account.yml
kubectl apply -n kubernetes-plugin-test-overridden-namespace2 -f src/test/kubernetes/service-account.yml
```

Also applicable to your situation is to create new Role and RoleBinding in default namespace referencing jenkins ServiceAccount from kubernetes-plugin namespace like so:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: role-jenkins-default
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: roleb-jenkins-default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: role-jenkins-default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: kubernetes-plugin
```

Note that `role-` and `roleb-` prefixes as well as `-deault` suffix are added to name for clarity. Same goes for explicitly listing namespace `default` for easier bookkeeping and clarity.

This change should get you past by the error mentioned in your question.